# Where is the best place to start projects and attract developers?

Tags: application-development, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu)

I want to develop software for Linux or cross-platform. I want to work with other open-source and non-profit developers. I want a place where Ubuntu or other developers come to start open-source or commercial projects, and we can join the projects or start our own projects.

I know there are social coding sites, but where can I start the project, and invite people or let people join? Then we can submit software to sourceforge.net. I know we can start projects at sourceforge.net, but is there anything more dedicated for Ubuntu developers,  especially for Ubuntu and for the Ubuntu Software Center?

Would you recommend Launchpad, sourceforge.net, github, gitorous or others?

Comment: already seen it i know how to develop apps for ubuntu read my question again

Comment: the forums and irc channels would be a good starting place

Comment: ...okay, I think I understand what you're looking for now. Edited to make it clearer what your needs are.

Comment: Possible *other* related question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/32084/why-does-ubuntu-use-launchpad-instead-of-github-or-bitbucket

Comment: Maybe better over on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to startups, new projects, technology news and major developments I keep pretty close tabs on [news.ycombinator.com](http://news.ycombinator.com)

Y Combinator is notorious for their investing into startups/new opportunities. Many a great developer keep an eye on it.

Comment: They are also notorious for fighting open source stuff. :(

Comment: It's a warring battle as investors want to protect their investment through various means while open source seeks to have a heavy community involvement. Will the user see investors? Likely not. Is it likely that other developers may take an interest and participate? Only one way to find out!

Comment: hey man any other place will sourceforge.net or laucnhpad do

Answer (score 1):

[Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/)? - Helps fund upcoming businesses through voluntary donations.